# Getting Crash on Startup when deployed to testflight EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, testflight, crash-reports

My app works fine locally, but when I deploy to TestFlight in iTunesConnect, I get crash on startup. Here is a log from crash report

```
{"app_name":"xxxx","timestamp":"2017-05-05 04:33:59.57 +0900","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"5a1b32d3-8f5c-31c7-b78d-46124be7926c","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1.0","bundleID":"com.au.Brixn","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)","incident_id":"243CC7A5-8109-4403-8931-092B88E008CC","name":"BrixnMobileUIiOS"}
Incident Identifier: 243CC7A5-8109-4403-8931-092B88E008CC
CrashReporter Key:   baae7bea05d866830a0eaca194b0b2a33727d6f0
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             BrixnMobileUIiOS [454]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E6840142-AE17-493B-96F4-25DA85E85B37/BrixnMobileUIiOS.app/BrixnMobileUIiOS
Identifier:          xxx
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.au.Brixn [469]


Date/Time:           2017-05-05 04:33:59.4838 +0900
Launch Time:         2017-05-05 04:33:58.3784 +0900
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187911014 0x1878f2000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879db334 0x1879d6000 + 21300
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001878859c4 0x187824000 + 399812
3   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001ad8a8 0x100070000 + 1300648
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001879d531c 0x1879cf000 + 25372
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879db334 0x1879d6000 + 21300
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001878859c4 0x187824000 + 399812
7   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002d07c8 0x100070000 + 2492360
8   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001f1e10 0x100070000 + 1580560
9   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001ad25c 0x100070000 + 1299036
10  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001ac388 0x100070000 + 1295240
11  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001a4010 0x100070000 + 1261584
12  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001005eb2e8 0x100070000 + 5747432
13  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001003f8d5c 0x100070000 + 3706204
14  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001003f7730 0x100070000 + 3700528
15  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100e64898 0x100070000 + 14633112
16  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100e3a0b4 0x100070000 + 14459060
17  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001005b4fc4 0x100070000 + 5525444
18  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001bbbf4 0x100070000 + 1358836
19  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100233428 0x100070000 + 1848360
20  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100233384 0x100070000 + 1848196
21  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000101cd0688 0x100070000 + 29755016
22  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000101cd0b8c 0x100070000 + 29756300
23  Foundation                      0x000000018940a4bc 0x189300000 + 1090748
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c5424 0x1887ea000 + 898084
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c4cfc 0x1887ea000 + 896252
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c29a0 0x1887ea000 + 887200
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001887f2d94 0x1887ea000 + 36244
28  GraphicsServices                0x000000018a25c074 0x18a250000 + 49268
29  UIKit                           0x000000018eaa4130 0x18ea2f000 + 479536
30  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100eca024 0x100070000 + 15048740
31  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100e5b18c 0x100070000 + 14594444
32  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100e5b14c 0x100070000 + 14594380
33  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002d5874 0x100070000 + 2513012
34  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001005b4fc4 0x100070000 + 5525444
35  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001bbbf4 0x100070000 + 1358836
36  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100233428 0x100070000 + 1848360
37  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002366d8 0x100070000 + 1861336
38  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001a0b68 0x100070000 + 1248104
39  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002d4ebc 0x100070000 + 2510524
40  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000101d073b4 0x100070000 + 29979572
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018780159c 0x1877fd000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187911a88 0x1878f2000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d7274 0x1879d6000 + 4724
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d7c 0x1879d6000 + 3452

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187911a88 0x1878f2000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d70a0 0x1879d6000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d7c 0x1879d6000 + 3452

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187911a88 0x1878f2000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d70a0 0x1879d6000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d7c 0x1879d6000 + 3452

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187910e1c 0x1878f2000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d88e4 0x1879d6000 + 10468
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000187301ac8 0x1872fa000 + 31432
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d19cc98 0x18c7e3000 + 10198168
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d19cc0c 0x18c7e3000 + 10198028
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d19caec 0x18c7e3000 + 10197740
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d19cd9c 0x18c7e3000 + 10198428
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878f3224 0x1878f2000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878f309c 0x1878f2000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c4e88 0x1887ea000 + 896648
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c2adc 0x1887ea000 + 887516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001887f2d94 0x1887ea000 + 36244
5   WebCore                         0x000000018d4bbb5c 0x18d479000 + 273244
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 6 name:  SGen worker
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187910e1c 0x1878f2000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d88e4 0x1879d6000 + 10468
2   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100291cf8 0x100070000 + 2235640
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 7 name:  Finalizer
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878f3260 0x1878f2000 + 4704
1   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001f4ad0 0x100070000 + 1592016
2   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100265114 0x100070000 + 2052372
3   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002b5e10 0x100070000 + 2383376
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d78 0x1879d6000 + 3448

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878f3224 0x1878f2000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878f309c 0x1878f2000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c4e88 0x1887ea000 + 896648
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c2adc 0x1887ea000 + 887516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001887f2d94 0x1887ea000 + 36244
5   Foundation                      0x000000018930cd64 0x189300000 + 52580
6   Foundation                      0x000000018932db34 0x189300000 + 187188
7   UIKit                           0x000000018f42e5f8 0x18ea2f000 + 10483192
8   Foundation                      0x000000018940a2c8 0x189300000 + 1090248
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878f3224 0x1878f2000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878f309c 0x1878f2000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c4e88 0x1887ea000 + 896648
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888c2adc 0x1887ea000 + 887516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001887f2d94 0x1887ea000 + 36244
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018883f9a0 0x1887ea000 + 350624
6   CoreMotion                      0x000000018f94303c 0x18f8d4000 + 454716
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 11 name:  tid_8c03
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187910e1c 0x1878f2000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d88e4 0x1879d6000 + 10468
2   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002b61c4 0x100070000 + 2384324
3   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010025c8d8 0x100070000 + 2017496
4   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100265114 0x100070000 + 2052372
5   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002b5e10 0x100070000 + 2383376
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 12 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187910e1c 0x1878f2000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d88e4 0x1879d6000 + 10468
2   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010025adf4 0x100070000 + 2010612
3   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010025d100 0x100070000 + 2019584
4   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100265114 0x100070000 + 2052372
5   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002b5e10 0x100070000 + 2383376
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 13 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187910e1c 0x1878f2000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d88e4 0x1879d6000 + 10468
2   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010025adf4 0x100070000 + 2010612
3   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010025d100 0x100070000 + 2019584
4   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100265114 0x100070000 + 2052372
5   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002b5e10 0x100070000 + 2383376
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 14 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187910e1c 0x1878f2000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d88e4 0x1879d6000 + 10468
2   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010025adf4 0x100070000 + 2010612
3   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010025d100 0x100070000 + 2019584
4   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100265114 0x100070000 + 2052372
5   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002b5e10 0x100070000 + 2383376
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 15 name:  tid_9803
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187910e1c 0x1878f2000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d88e4 0x1879d6000 + 10468
2   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002bc128 0x100070000 + 2408744
3   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002baf54 0x100070000 + 2404180
4   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002bad0c 0x100070000 + 2403596
5   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002a2660 0x100070000 + 2303584
6   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100225d1c 0x100070000 + 1793308
7   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100472f3c 0x100070000 + 4206396
8   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001004728dc 0x100070000 + 4204764
9   BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100472930 0x100070000 + 4204848
10  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010045c0d4 0x100070000 + 4112596
11  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001012e3d78 0x100070000 + 19348856
12  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001012e3b30 0x100070000 + 19348272
13  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001012da3ec 0x100070000 + 19309548
14  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001005b4fc4 0x100070000 + 5525444
15  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001bbbf4 0x100070000 + 1358836
16  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100233428 0x100070000 + 1848360
17  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001a5b3c 0x100070000 + 1268540
18  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001005b73f0 0x100070000 + 5534704
19  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100543998 0x100070000 + 5061016
20  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001012d82b4 0x100070000 + 19301044
21  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100464b30 0x100070000 + 4148016
22  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100464344 0x100070000 + 4145988
23  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100464ab4 0x100070000 + 4147892
24  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010047171c 0x100070000 + 4200220
25  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010047155c 0x100070000 + 4199772
26  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001004649f4 0x100070000 + 4147700
27  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100464834 0x100070000 + 4147252
28  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010046e8d8 0x100070000 + 4188376
29  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100473800 0x100070000 + 4208640
30  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010047171c 0x100070000 + 4200220
31  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010047155c 0x100070000 + 4199772
32  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001004714d4 0x100070000 + 4199636
33  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x000000010047386c 0x100070000 + 4208748
34  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001005b4fc4 0x100070000 + 5525444
35  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001001bbbf4 0x100070000 + 1358836
36  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x0000000100233428 0x100070000 + 1848360
37  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002651d4 0x100070000 + 2052564
38  BrixnMobileUIiOS                0x00000001002b5e10 0x100070000 + 2383376
39  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d975c 0x1879d6000 + 14172
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d966c 0x1879d6000 + 13932
41  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001879d6d84 0x1879d6000 + 3460

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000000000002a
    x4: 0x000000000000001b   x5: 0x000000016fd8b660   x6: 0x0000000000000030   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x0000000102328000  x13: 0x000000000000a0b3  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x000000000000a0b3
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000188811c00  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001ae359b40  x21: 0x0000000101dbd251  x22: 0x000000016fd8ba48  x23: 0x0000000101dbd204
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001033f5138  x26: 0x000000010260e130  x27: 0x000000010301b400
   x28: 0x0000000102302280   fp: 0x000000016fd8b9e0   lr: 0x00000001879db334
    sp: 0x000000016fd8b9c0   pc: 0x0000000187911014 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100070000 - 0x101df3fff BrixnMobileUIiOS arm64  <5a1b32d38f5c31c7b78d46124be7926c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E6840142-AE17-493B-96F4-25DA85E85B37/BrixnMobileUIiOS.app/BrixnMobileUIiOS
0x1020f4000 - 0x102127fff dyld arm64  <a63e8b89c75a3115b54b1f2f469f676a> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1872f8000 - 0x1872f9fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <6d9ab1f5df1b36d89fd5675936e3da5e> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1872fa000 - 0x18734ffff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <4d91c4d8858339c7ae2b3716d1f5e0fc> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x187350000 - 0x18736cfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <5615fb6378773e82a20d5d0727a6132e> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x187370000 - 0x18774dfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <64c3c5a56c7a30c39ff4a3ec74426cf4> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x18774e000 - 0x187752fff libcache.dylib arm64  <f507d09bab2d343c9b9c53a05986909b> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x187753000 - 0x18775efff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <0bd3d4cb2d803c6caf1d09e54e8dc705> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x18775f000 - 0x187762fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <c2952c9143233a30bbad9ffd3535c47c> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x187763000 - 0x18776afff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <ee8e1650db9b3a57b3e517677ef1da49> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x18776b000 - 0x1877ccfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <1662015f100e3fab8573f40889935a98> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1877cd000 - 0x1877fcfff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <46e0cb2039333474ba7b47b131153bd5> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1877fd000 - 0x187801fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <649eb4fd79bf30869584b3ec86b6bcbc> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x187802000 - 0x187802fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <985c8570c8603f8886372c8fe4843f08> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x187803000 - 0x187808fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <3fdc8b3ebe27315aa71cadf73b0e0642> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x187809000 - 0x18780afff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <7e353a2221703ccd99c8bb04a0bdc3dd> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18780b000 - 0x187822fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <2f456d47db4937c5aa3dee82ab2550ee> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x187823000 - 0x187823fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <373b4d279e6432d5b718ec5b71aebfc4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x187824000 - 0x1878a0fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <d31511075c1b38bcbc5198a7f40447b5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1878a1000 - 0x1878a5fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <1db4aaed5fdc3cd592a52f7358d1c666> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x1878a6000 - 0x1878abfff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <15235799c22434b78bfd0f93cdc2c9dc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x1878ac000 - 0x1878adfff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <31d817e729333cd6be4695ade5abf990> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x1878ae000 - 0x1878c6fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <099dd5a82bed308882bc1782787b23cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x1878c7000 - 0x1878cdfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <58d80a29aee7360ab16718545b8102a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x1878ce000 - 0x1878f1fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <d0d5a77de46631fca60abd5313794ef1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1878f2000 - 0x187916fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <2ccf4db33c323a68b05942b8375b90c2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x187917000 - 0x187943fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <d2b0172418503909a26678ae48b1269c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x187944000 - 0x18795ffff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <44978732283439fc92fff8e3ab817123> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x187960000 - 0x1879b9fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <e59c5c150b41309481d185ca548ec114> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x1879ba000 - 0x1879c3fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <4d2d53bd1d0133209b896e201160a682> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1879c4000 - 0x1879cefff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <fb43e04c8d8e3001bd73370115b6abd4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1879cf000 - 0x1879d5fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <021e2b400d1b36f1927cd8b9ef5771ff> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1879d6000 - 0x1879dffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <ec957ca38cdb3ff39a675b484d59d580> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1879e0000 - 0x1879e3fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <1a659aa7dc7f34d988fda8e46bbd67d6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1879e4000 - 0x1879ebfff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <29eb26c4ca5c3bd0aaf1f8bd8ce2e600> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1879ec000 - 0x1879fefff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <a42d46c7e3463233b75873d1e3ac2267> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1879ff000 - 0x187a04fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <0963fc28375630e68ccd844e4f48d1b2> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x187a05000 - 0x187a05fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <acccc912f98833088c662f78ec126fe2> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x187a06000 - 0x187a2cfff libxpc.dylib arm64  <9bf3e86d19f1318a9b1906a2681cf234> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x187a2d000 - 0x187c42fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <8784ed7062a139ad9c768ed801bb5c8f> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x187c43000 - 0x187c54fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <76ea48b2d8053291891a800d76088c09> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1887ea000 - 0x188b6bfff CoreFoundation arm64  <106dcfdae2ac31b9af16e54e3fdb49be> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x188b6c000 - 0x188b7cfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <e663bf7a74f43aad9f86229b0b29f376> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x188b7d000 - 0x188b7dfff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <6ec005a9a0a931da96fff946b027ca37> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x188b7e000 - 0x188bf9fff IOKit arm64  <04198d723e7f3834914ae5869c25e65c> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x188bfa000 - 0x188c1afff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <648fed3bf8af3ccdbd24e5c65e81ceb5> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x188c1b000 - 0x188d04fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <29f6e338c1f13348970811ca0f0fe293> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x188d05000 - 0x188d9ffff Security arm64  <2423134e64f939aba8368d62495f8197> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x188da0000 - 0x188e0bfff SystemConfiguration arm64  <e8aaab6905853f7e97fb492185cf20be> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x188e0c000 - 0x188f1cfff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <f1a568e393d531f6af5e1edb816cdab2> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x188f1d000 - 0x189291fff CFNetwork arm64  <7074b3e719d23257b4cd53899121f5c8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x189292000 - 0x18929ffff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <64376e53acd732f3b5c85ee50b4f01c1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1892a0000 - 0x1892b8fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <7b9227fb2acb3feda1bffd6427b92fd5> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1892b9000 - 0x1892d3fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <7c6afb4c2fb13be9a84cf6d72ce823d8> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1892d4000 - 0x1892fdfff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <d8f6218802123a0ca0ec0d922a65c9a6> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1892fe000 - 0x1892fffff liblangid.dylib arm64  <c78b76c300b036c6852e9ff59b9b5e0a> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x189300000 - 0x1895cffff Foundation arm64  <73ff2b76d90f3c90b0108f6e36e3b71f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1895d0000 - 0x18967bfff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <8efc2fffcc8d3817a73da84ffd232d46> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x18967c000 - 0x1899aafff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <13c0d7676f6a381aa399570bf0142738> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1899ab000 - 0x189c45fff vImage arm64  <8984ca1dbdd4341593c2532a3f112644> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x189c46000 - 0x189c6bfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <1fc0b5b5a59c3ae78efa0a4124bf69b0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x189c6c000 - 0x189c80fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <39992b5d7f8a38e7b46ab952e44aa2f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x189c81000 - 0x189c92fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <b0af26c688c631508453fd8f08cf1d0b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x189c93000 - 0x189d08fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <dab772660509376eb918a2c72163797e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x189d09000 - 0x189d09fff vecLib arm64  <6c742a3f1ad83395a1a5f3fc1abd56f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x189d0a000 - 0x189d0afff Accelerate arm64  <166a50b815443ce89269964414cfd7b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x189d0b000 - 0x18a24ffff CoreGraphics arm64  <f8a6e0de80b23cb8b41654b953606846> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x18a250000 - 0x18a264fff GraphicsServices arm64  <93b597044b5234749061bb64ddf8adae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18a265000 - 0x18a2b2fff AppSupport arm64  <b9af4ec39608345594622765e98d4f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18a2b3000 - 0x18a3e0fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <d07c54225af93b6289780c72418e3c9f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18a3e1000 - 0x18a442fff BaseBoard arm64  <7aa95ea0660f325db0c7e793a3193cc5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18a443000 - 0x18a452fff AssertionServices arm64  <4cef0d85a60b329e858109f9638abd7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18a453000 - 0x18a480fff BackBoardServices arm64  <322bd4e181fa3e77b99133e48e785e6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18a485000 - 0x18a4d4fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <49204359a9843dd8ad769c64bc8f468f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18a4d8000 - 0x18a50cfff SpringBoardServices arm64  <d573996d93083f05bf72c1ab6e9a64a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x18a50d000 - 0x18a527fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <f0cc77ecdbbd37b8a31aa6ea6107c2ae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18a528000 - 0x18a530fff IOSurface arm64  <419bcf22d97732bd99f6f7bb6b50e133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x18a531000 - 0x18a53cfff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <e262bbe5419e3e5ba65b1bbe05144dcf> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x18a53d000 - 0x18a553fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <c3b0e870e0ac38d892b690dab53f3306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18a554000 - 0x18a556fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <d51a80f830d9315192eed78bc4ea2383> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18a557000 - 0x18a597fff AppleJPEG arm64  <557e7ca7706f3ab5883060b4d3b375d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18a598000 - 0x18ab24fff ImageIO arm64  <4732d269b83036408adbb7a9c9d28f55> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x18ab25000 - 0x18ab2bfff TCC arm64  <14d745587f8b3fa2b6f9e604d76237f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x18ab2c000 - 0x18ab30fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <9bb5dc9d93da36d5914ffd26dabf0306>
```

I have no idea how to read this report and I cannot replicate this issue locally.

Comment: Try to symbolicate crash log using Xcode, it gives more information why the app is crashing and post new log, check this, how to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html